# Is there any way to reset or delete Save the World progress in Fortnite?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-save-the-world

How can I wipe all Save the World progress in Fortnite Season 5 (Xbox). I have looked in the game settings and Epic Games forums to no avail. Can I wipe it manually or would I need to contact Epic Games?

Comment: This forum might help:


  http://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/community/new-to-fortnite/157647-how-can-i-restart-the-whole-game-save-the-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not unless you make a new epic games account and start from scratch completely! This would require you buying the game all over again!

Answer (score 0):

I made a [sheets document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S_Znid1WriLlNPSXT2neTnGBCqwrLpfeowxRa0E9Q7k/edit?usp=sharing) for this!

It's not a complete reset, but it's worked for me. You can recycle all of your schematics, heroes, and suvivors, then track how many items you gain with this sheet. Feel free to make a copy if you want to try it out.

If you need new lines, then you can hold shift to select the last row, and then paste in more space for resources.